# Cannot find namespace "ServiceModel" with Unity

Tags: wcf, namespaces, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2013

I would like to use a WCF Service (via Named Pipe) in my Unity application. Thus, I include the following two Namespaces:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
```

After I run my project in Unity, this leads to the following two errors:

```
Assets/Scripts/program.cs(4,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespaceSystem'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Assets/Scripts/program.cs(5,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespaceSystem'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Next, I changed the Unity script editor from MonoDevelop to Visual Studio 2013. After I open the same script in Visual Studio, the term "ServiceModel" is underlined (zigzag red line) and Visual Studio says that this Namespace is not available. After I add "System.ServiceModel" manually, those red lines disappear. But when I run it from Unity, I get the same error again. Also, when I restart Unity and go back to that script in Visual Studio, again I have to add "System.ServiceModel" manually.

I hope you understand what I mean.
How can I permanently include "System.ServiceModel" and "System.ServiceModel.Channels"?

Note, I am currently using a trial version of Visual Studio Pro and Unity Pro. Could that be an issue?

Comment: It's likely Unity simply doesn't support WCF in its subset of Mono.  If you can't find it on Unity's [compatibility page](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) you might have to find an alternate solution.

Comment: OK, but according to [Webservices In Unity](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Webservices_In_Unity) it is supported

Comment: Does this `Mono Compatibility` list actually hold true when using Visual Studio instead of MonoDevelop?

Comment: Have you followed that post's instructions and copied `System.ServiceModel.dll` to `Assets/Plugins`?  And yes, the compatibility page is relevant to both IDEs.  Visual Studio + Unity uses Unity's C# compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I just copied the file *System.ServiceModel.dll* to my newly created Assets\Plugin directory. The error disappeared :-). However, I am having another error now.

With the following commands, I want to create a proxy of type *NamedPipe*.

```
ChannelFactory<ClassName> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<ClassName>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(),new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));               
ClassName pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
```

When I run my code, I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Channel type IDuplexSessionChannel is not supported.
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeChannelFactory`1[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IDuplexSessionChannel].OnCreateChannel (System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address, System.Uri via)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IDuplexSessionChannel].CreateChannel (System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress, System.Uri via)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
>   Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232)
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientRuntimeChannel..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime runtime, System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription contract, TimeSpan openTimeout, TimeSpan closeTimeout, IChannel contextChannel, IChannelFactory factory, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress, System.Uri via)
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientRuntimeChannel..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory channelFactory, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress, System.Uri via)
>   __clientproxy_ClassName..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint , System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory , System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress , System.Uri )
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:513)
>   Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:519)
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:528)
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:338)
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args, System.Object[] activationAttributes) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:268)
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:263)
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ClassName].CreateChannel (System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address, System.Uri via)
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ClassName].CreateChannel (System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address)
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ClassName].CreateChannel ()
>   IDL_vehicle.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/IDL_vehicle.cs:30)