# Visual Studio showing errors when referencing external assemblies in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

This is basically an *aftermath* question after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009716/cannot-reference-system-servicemodel-in-unity) I posted yesterday. Long story short, I had troubles referencing `System.ServiceModel` in my Unity application and I got that fixed by having this `mcs.rsp file`:

```
-r:System.ServiceModel.dll
```

And by having `Scripting Runtime Version` and `Api Compability Level` settings aligned to `.NET 4.x`. However, now I am facing another issue.

#### Unity project builds fine!

So, let me first point out that my project runs fine without compile errors. So on that regard it is just fine. The problem I am facing is an annoyance that I am getting in Visual Studio and impacts my development experience.

#### Errors in Visual Studio

Basically when I open the C# project in Visual Studio, I get type errors like this:

[image]

Even though assembly `System.ServiceModel` is now **correctly loaded** in the project, Visual Studio shows me errors complaining about the fact that those highlighted types are not available.

> The type or namespace "ServiceHost" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why? This is extremely annoying when developing, I cannot possibly carry out a whole development with fake errors showing up like this :(

#### A few more info...

If I inspect generated project file `Assembly-CSharp.csproj`, I can see this:

```
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex">
    <HintPath>C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http">
   <HintPath>C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp">
    <HintPath>C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives">
    <HintPath>C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security">
    <HintPath>C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Security.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

So it makes me wonder:

- Seems like Unity is pointing to the mono generated dlls of the required dlls. However where is `System.ServiceModel.dll`?
- I can see there is `System.ServiceModel.dll` in the folder containing `Facades`, why isn't that used?

Comment: Mono has “limited” WCF support if that is what you are doing with System.ServiceModel https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/

Comment: @User453465436754: Yes I see :( But I wonder how developers achieve online gamig in Unity. How do they operate the communication between remote players?

Comment: Games use very efficient network lean; speedy and often proprietary (nothing wrong with that) protocols as opposed to anything SOAP; REST; or Protobuf have to offer, hence no reliance on `System.ServiceModel.dll`

Comment: @User453465436754: I see. Just out of curiosity, can you link a reference about how to build this connectivity in a game with Unity? I am just curious to see if I can maybe look at that practice to solve my problem.

Comment: Best bet is to have a look over at [gamedev](http://gamedev.net).  Generally you will find peeps use IP Datagrams for it's broadcast and faster aspects

Comment: For this specific error, checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040904/cannot-find-namespace-servicemodel-with-unity

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you are not using the proper dll. In order to use anything from the `System.ServiceModel` and `System.ServiceModel.Description` namespace, you must reference the proper mono dll that comes with Unity.

First, change the `Scripting Runtime Version` and `Api Compatibility Level`  to *4.x* or *.NET 4.6 Equivalent* (Options depends on Unity version).

Go to to `<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5` or for example, `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5` on my computer.

Once in this directory, copy `System.ServiceModel.dll` to your `<Project>\Assets` path and you should be able to use `ServiceHost` and `ServiceEndpoint` API.

You may still get a run-time error or exception since this is mono but this should fix your current compile-time error. *Don't forget to undo what you've already done in your question before doing what's in this answer.*

Comment: Quoting from [Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileAssemblies.html): "You should reference class library assemblies as described in the example above. Don’t copy them into the Project directory."

Comment: I wanted to edit the comment at the beginning because I am just angry that this is not working but StackOverflow does not let change comments after 5 minutes. I seriously owe you an apology for those first words. I wanted to change them into: "This is not the solution I was looking for unfortunately". Please accept my apologies for being rude! Seriously. Again, I am just frustrated because I've been spending the whole day on this. I am very very sorry.

Comment: That being said, what I was trying to say, sorry out of anger, is that this is probably not the best practice here. I am not looking for a hack unfortunately but for a best practice. I just think it is very strange that Unity does not reference the proper dlls when knowing that a certain set of assemblies is not supported in the current profile. The `System.ServiceModel` dll is available also in different versions, like in version 3.5. f the one in 4.x is not completely supported, they could generate the project to reference the supported one. Unless no WCF is supported at all, then that's it